# Remove a div with it's child elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a method from where I need to remove the current div with it's element on clink. But it's not doing anything. I have searched goggle for it and applied various thing but no result. Can anyone please help me on this please?!!! Here are my code below ::

my div where my elements and remove link are stated >>>

```
<div class="col-xs-4 pNorPpl" id="pPeople">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="participatedPeopleName"><g:message code="sl" default="সদস্যের নাম" /></label>
                <g:textField id="participatedPeopleName" name="participatedPeopleName" class="form-control"/>
                <a onclick="addAnotherNormalPeople()">Add More</a> ||
                <a onclick="removeThisMember()">Remove</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

my remove function >>>

```
function removeThisMember(){
    $(this).closest('.pNorPpl').remove();
}
```

Comment: Have you added $(document).ready to register this event?

Comment: pass your elem to the function, like removeThisMember(this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context of `this` does not carry through when you use `on*` attributes. Instead you need to pass it:

```
<a onclick="removeThisMember(this)">Remove</a>
```

```js
function removeThisMember(el) {
    $(el).closest('.pNorPpl').remove();
}
```

Or you can attach your event via jQuery:

```
<a href="#" class="remove-link">Remove</a>
```

```js
$('.pNorPpl').on('click', '.remove-link', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.pNotPpl').remove();
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Your code is working only with the first element. But not in cloned element. I am adding this div to add more member. But remove is working only on the first. I have checked the class of cloned div. Is is the same as parent/first. Then why it's not working on other div except parents?!! I am really confused. Can you help please ??

Comment: In that case you need to use a delegated event hander. I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's working fine. Now I need to set the value to "" when it is removed.

Comment: Why would you need to do that? If the element has been removed from the DOM it no longer has a value attribute to set.

Comment: When I want to remove it then I will remove it, but when I will update some info such as delete an user then I will not remove it , just hide it and set a value to delete it in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this solution:
http://jsbin.com/tuniyucuki/1

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-4 pNorPpl" id="pPeople">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="participatedPeopleName"><g:message code="sl" default="সদস্যের নাম" /></label>
            <g:textField id="participatedPeopleName" name="participatedPeopleName" class="form-control"/>
            <a onclick="addAnotherNormalPeople()">Add More</a> ||
            <a class="removeFromHere" >Remove</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.removeFromHere').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.pNorPpl').remove();
  })
})
```